# OWIN OAuth 2.0 - Bearer Token Never Expire

Tags: .net, oauth, owin, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using the following OAuth provider and options:

```
    UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
        AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/AccountOwin/ExternalLogin"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
        AllowInsecureHttp = true
    };
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

The Oauth Provider class comes from the below link:
https://github.com/gustavo-armenta/BearerTokenAuthenticationSample/blob/master/BearerTokenAuthenticationSample/Providers/ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs

I want to implement Refresh token provider and because of this I set the expiration time to 2 minutes. But I noticed that the WEB API alows the acces to the resources even after 2 minutes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the full sample or are you applying it to your own code? Do you have the [Authorize] attribute applied to the end point you are accessing?

Comment: Yes I'm sure that I'm using the Authorize attribute. Without a valid Token I can't reach my resources but I set the expiration time to 2 minutes but after that I still can reach the resources with that token. That is why I'm curious about it. In all examples I saw that everybody set the expiration day to more then one day.

Comment: @HaveThunk maybe I'm using wrong the example? It's weird, and I still have the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem because I'd forgotten to configure WebAPI correctly. Adding the following code into my WebApiConfig Register() method solved it.

```
// Web API configuration and services
// Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

I found this in [the sample I used](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api) and it's also mentioned in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/20/understanding-security-features-in-spa-template.aspx).

Comment: I'm using the same setup in my config file. But the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem.  In our case it turned out to be that the authentication server was built with web api 2.0 and the resource server was web api 2.2. We built the authentication server first.  Then built the resource server.  By the time we built the resource server and added the Nuget packages, we got web api 2.2.  Upgrading the packages to the new versions on the authentication server and redeploying solved our problem.