# The entity type IdentityUser is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I see the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914658/owin-oauth-provider-the-entity-type-identityuser-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-t) question, but the scenario presented there doesn't seem to apply so I think I have a different issue. In fact, I'm seeing several questions on SO that are similar, each with different causes and solutions, so I think this error must be caused from a high level. That said...

I have an EF code-first database model and I'm trying to use `IdentityUser` to extend a standard registration for my MVC 5 site.

I have my extended `UserModel`:

```cs
namespace MyMvcSite.Models 
{
    public class UserModel : IdentityUser 
    {
        public string BillingId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<DatabaseModel> Databases { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my context:

```cs
using MyMvcSite.Models;

namespace MyMvcSite.Web 
{
    public class AuthContext : IdentityDbContext<UserModel> 
    {
        public AuthContext() : base("AuthContext") { }
    }
}
```

Now, when I execute the code to register a user:

```cs
public async Task<IdentityResult> RegisterUser(UserModel user) 
{
    user.Email = user.UserName;
    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
    
    return result;
}
```

I get this error:

> The entity type IdentityUser is not part of the model for the current context.

I can't figure out what this error means, because it looks like I have everything correct. Can anyone tell what might be going wrong???

I know my connectionString `AuthContext` is correct because I have used it previously.

Comment: How do you instantiate your `_userManager` and its `context`?  This seems like it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893710/the-entity-type-applicationuser-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context

Comment: My `_userManager` was initialized to: `_userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(_ctx));`. I changed it to `_userManager = new UserManager<UserModel>(new UserStore<UserModel>(_ctx));`, which solved it! Post this as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you are using a custom user class with ASP.NET Identity, you have to make sure that you explicitly specify the custom user class type `<T>` to both the `UserManager` and the `UserStore` on instantiation.

```
private UserManager<UserModel> _userManager;

public AccountController()
{
    AuthContext _ctx = new AuthContext();

    UserStore<UserModel> userStore = new UserStore<UserModel>(_ctx);
    _userManager = new UserManager<UserModel>(userStore);     
}
```

or in shorter form (like your reply comment):

```
private UserManager<UserModel> _userManager;

public AccountController()
{
    AuthContext _ctx = new AuthContext();    
    _userManager = new UserManager<UserModel>(new UserStore<UserModel>(_ctx));     
}
```

If the type is allowed to defaulted to `IdentityUser` when you want to use a custom class you will experience the error you reported.

Comment: Thanks! Perfecto!

Answer (score 11):

I was having this same problem, and I recall having a similar problem working with SimpleMembership in MVC4.

I’m doing database first development, so I have an EDMX file. Turns out, ASP.NET Identity does not like the connection string that is created when you generate your .edmx model file. If you are using a. EDM connection string in :base(“EDMConnString”) you will most likely have this problem.

I fixed this by creating a standard connection string that pointed to the database where the ASP.NET Identity tables are (in my case the same database), used that connection string in :base, and it worked.

Something like this

```
<add name="IdentityConnection" connectionString="data source=THEJUS\SQLSERVER2014;initial catalog=IdentitySample;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=IdentitySample.Admin" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Yes. That solved my problem. There are 2 connection strings needed. One for Identity stuff and one for EF. If you look in Web.Config you will see a Default Connection and then one EF makes when you configure it during installing it. You can easily build a dummy MVC5 and add EF to see them and use them if your database is the same.

My problem was caused by an MVC 5 app that I added EF later (Data first by the way). Then I deleted the "DefaultConnection" thinking I wouldn't need it. So Identity uses the connection referenced in base. EF uses whatever entity model you set at top of controller.

Comment: MyModelEntities _db = new MyModelEntities();

Comment: Thank you @JustJohn, this is FINALLY what worked for me!

Comment: I have the same problem, I created both connection strings but, where do I say to use one or other connection string?

Answer (score 6):

I got this error when I introduced DI to my project. Using AutoFac and Identity I had to add the following: `builder.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>().As<DbContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();`

Without this, when AutoFac was creating my UserStore instance, it was using the default `UserStore()` ctor which creates a new `IdentityDbContext`, not my `ApplicationDbContext`.

With this line, `UserStore(DbContext context)` ctor gets called, with my `ApplicationDbContext`.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is some step i figured out while resolving this issue**

1. First Check your database for Table of ASP.Net Identity
2. Create these table on your database if not exist you can also apply migration
3. Check the below image and verify your code

[Register Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2M7X.png)

[IdentityDbContext Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yf7Mi.png)