# MVC 5: The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context. (DB first Approach)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

```
    The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.
    Line 76:             // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    Line 77:             // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to 
    shouldLockout: true
    Line 78:             var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, 
    model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    Line 79:             switch (result)
    Line 80:             {
```

[InvalidOperationException: The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.]
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType) +4307818
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +38
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +54 System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Include(String path) +18
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.Include(String path) +68 System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include(IQueryable`1 source, String path) +135
System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 path) +188
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.GetUserAggregateAsync(Expression`1 filter) +260
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.FindByNameAsync(String userName) +536 Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.FindByNameAsync(String userName) +56
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d__4.MoveNext() +376
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d__0.MoveNext() +242
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d__0.MoveNext() +558
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d__d.MoveNext() +550
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +29 OperationsDashboard.Web.Controllers.<Register>d__15.MoveNext() in E:\2018_project\Smartwires\Operations Dashboard\Development\7-16-2020\OperationsDashboard\OperationsDashboard.Web\Controllers\AccountController.cs:155 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64 System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +228 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9836613
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

```
    <add name="myconnectionstring" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.my_database.csdl|res://*/Models.my_database.ssdl|res://*/Models.my_database.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=Operations_DB_1;integrated security=False;user id=sa;password=sa123;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

IdentityConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using OperationsDashboard.Web.Models;

namespace OperationsDashboard.Web
{
    public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }

    public class SmsService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            // Plug in your SMS service here to send a text message.
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }

    // Configure the application user manager used in this application. UserManager is defined in ASP.NET Identity and is used by the application.
    public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            // Configure validation logic for usernames
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true,
            };

            // Configure user lockout defaults
            manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
            manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

            // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
            // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                Subject = "Security Code",
                BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
            manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
            var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider = 
                    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
            }
            return manager;
        }
    }

    // Configure the application sign-in manager which is used in this application.
    public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
    {
        public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
            : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
        {
        }

        public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
        }

        public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
        }
    }
}
```

```
IdentityModels.cs
```

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace OperationsDashboard.Web.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("myconnectionstring", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: look at this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893710/the-entity-type-applicationuser-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context

Comment: Determine the connection "myconnectionstring" ,is it like a sample ? didn't forget to set that ?

Comment: This post may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26208708/the-entity-type-identityuser-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context/26247529#26247529

Comment: Mohsen Zahedi yes it is sample. i have changed it as my connectionstring name.